# Menu entries not being translated

Tags: multi-sites

I have sitemap, and I would like to display the menu in the primary language of the site.  However, as this screenshot shows, some items are still being displayed in English:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where are those links coming from?  Are they provided by nodes?  Modules?  What i18n modules are you using?

Comment: come from menu ,no it is provided by sitemap model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I miss to determine the language of the menu ... I am stupid it fix by adding the language of each menu i wanna to display on specific language like this
[image]